# Change image added using android:drawableRight on radio button dynamically

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a radio group and 3 radio buttons in it. I have added images to the right of each radio button using `android:drawableRight`.. Can i change the image added using android:drawableRight dynamically??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes You can change it dynamically..
You can use `setCompoundDrawables(drawable_left, drawable_top, drawable_right, drawable_bottom)`

Here is sample code. Try & check it.

```
radiobutton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, your_drawable, null);
```